# How to Accept Orders on Woocommerce as per location?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce website hosted on domain https://www.micropediaglobal.com.

I have one requirement that my different branch managers located at different locations should see the orders as per the locators and process their orders only.

Can someone please guide here ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Website Development Company](https://www.micropediaglobal.com/) website does not seems to be on wordpress, however you can bifurcate or process woocommerce orders location wise as below:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['xerox_shop_name'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'xeroxshopmeta', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['xerox_shop_name'] ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Xerox Center Name').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'xeroxshopmeta', true ) . '</p>';
}

//add custom field column

add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION' );
function MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = ( is_array( $columns ) ) ? $columns : array();
    unset( $new_columns[ 'order_actions' ] );

    //edit this for your column(s)
    //all of your columns will be added before the actions column
    $new_columns['xeroxColumn'] = 'Xerox Center Name';


    //stop editing
    $new_columns[ 'order_actions' ] = $columns[ 'order_actions' ];
    return $new_columns;
}


add_filter( "manage_edit-shop_order_sortable_columns", 'MY_COLUMNS_SORT_FUNCTION' );
function MY_COLUMNS_SORT_FUNCTION( $columns ) 
{
    $custom = array(
            'xeroxColumn'    => 'xeroxshopmeta', 

            );
    return wp_parse_args( $custom, $columns );
}


add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION', 2 );
function MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION( $column ) {
    global $post;
    $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID );

    //start editing, I was saving my fields for the orders as custom post meta
    //if you did the same, follow this code

    if ( $column == 'xeroxColumn' ) {
        echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'xeroxshopmeta', true );


    }

}
```

Comment: I think, this is useful, I will check and this and get back to you.